# Use bind_result to push into array

Tags: php

Is it possible to use bind_result and bind all of the columns into an array? The reason I ask is because I execute the code on lots of different tables and don't want to have to put each column in when the amount changes.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM " . $company . " WHERE `id` = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $route);

$route = $_GET['routeid'];

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($test);
```

Currently that's what my PHP looks like. Clearly it's wrong because you must bind them to something, I just need to know how to put the data into an array and bind it to that (hoping you can understand that poor explanation).

Thanks

PS. I've looked at the related answer and it only confused me. If someone could explain in a little more detail I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you specifically want to use `bind_result` to do this when a more natural alternative already exists?

```
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // do something with $row
}
```

If [`fetch_assoc`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) is not exactly what you want, other variations include [`fetch_row`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) (numeric indexing) and [`fetch_object`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php).

Comment: Thanks very much. The source I read made out it was a requirement to use bind_result, after doing more reading I understand where it should be correctly used now. Thanks for your answer, I will use that. :)

Comment: @Jon `get_result()` needs *mysqlnd* drivers. With my hosting server I don't have mysqlnd drivers. In that case is there any option available?

Comment: @JJPA: You can use `bind_result` and `fetch`, but then you extract the values into separate variables and not into a single array per row. See example #1 in http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php

Comment: @Jon thank you for the reply. But it looks like I have to write too much get get an associative array. Anyways thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt->bind_result($test['col1'], $test['col2']);
```

Continue adding $test['colX'] for however many columns you have.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't answer my question. I stated that the amount of columns would vary from table to table, but I thank you for your answer. :)